# C# Hash Algorithm is not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash

I have  passwordHash and passwordSalt in my user model and database for register. I am posting email and password to my API. I am getting user by email from database, and I am hashing coming password from API. Furthermore, I compare to each other, but it isn't working correctly

I worked like that a lot of times, but I have never lived trouble, I upgraded my operating system to Windows 11. I don't know, maybe it is reason Windows 11.

```
 public class HashingHelper
    {
        public static void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }

        public static bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));

                for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (computedHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

`CreatePasswordHash` method is hashing password before register.
`VerifyPasswordHash` method is comparing  coming password from API and coming password from my database

Comment: Why are you doing this. Asp.net has build in user management like Identity > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity. No need to build your own password stuff

Comment: It's not really clear from the description specifically what operations are being performed on what values, and some of the statements in the description almost make it sound like the *stored* password is not hashed.  Please clarify the specific debugging steps and runtime values producing the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, :)  I know this, but I just would like to build my own password stuff for experience.  @vdwwd

Comment: Okay, Thanks @David. I forgot to write in description, I compare passwords after All password has been hashed. I will try it again. Thank you for your helping. :)

Comment: FWIW building your own password stuff is incredibly difficult and should not be taken on lightly. I 100% guarantee you will make your application vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Do your own "passwordstuff" **to learn why you should not attempt this for production code**. In production, stand on the shoulders of giants.

Comment: Thank you so much for all suggestions. :))

Comment: Looks like it should work. You should provide example inputs and outputs for which it fails. My guess is you are not correctly storing/retrieving  the hash and/or salt in the database.